# Unable to retrieve data from my sql to java eclipse

Tags: java, mysql

Im unable to retrieve data from mysql to java eclipse console. How do i retrieve and display the data from mysql.

**DB TABLE Columns are**: Student_ID | Student_FirstName | Student_LastName | Student_EmailID | Student_Course

Here is the code below:

```
package jdbcdemo;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.sql.ResultSet;  
import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;

public class StudentDetail {

    public static void studentinfo() {

        System.out.println("Enter the stdentid to view details");

        Scanner studentid= new Scanner(System.in);
        int stdnumber = studentid.nextInt();
        studentid.nextLine();

        //Connection to db
        try{
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/student_db","root","admin");
        Statement stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
        String details = "SELECT * FROM `student_db`.`studentinfo` WHERE `Student_ID`='"+stdnumber+"'";
        ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery(details);

        }catch (Exception e){
            System.err.println(e);
        }

    }

}
```

Output : there is no error displayed and "EXIT" is displayed as output.

Comment: What output are you expecting? You're not doing anything with the `ResultSet`.

Comment: i tried if loopif(rs.next()) { 
      int Student_ID = rs.getInt("Student_ID"); 
      String Student_FirstName = rs.getString("Student_FirstName");
      String Student_LastName = rs.getString("Student_LastName");
      String Student_EmailID = rs.getString("Student_EmailID");
      String Student_Course = rs.getString("Student_Course");
     }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After querying the table (which you have done), you need to extract the data from the [`ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html). E.g.:

```
ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery(details);
while (rs.next()) {
      System.out.println ("Student ID: " + rs.getString(1);
      System.out.println ("Student name: " + rs.getString(2);
}
```

Comment: It worked great, i tried if loop and had problem print the out put...Thanks